# FORALL usage in BULK COLLECT in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hello I have a procedure and questions about it. This procedure is used for extracting data then inserting them into one table. I realized that we dont use loop while in FORALL syntax. So my purpose is that extracting 10.000 records then inserting these 10.000 records into a single table. What I want to know is that, the procedure just stops after inserting 10.000 records or continues its' work? I am asking because there is no loop inside FORALL?
My second question is that should I remove v_cnt and IF MOD (v_cnt, 10000) = 0 lines in the script?

I am adding scripts below, I am open to any fix advices or anything else thank you from now.

```
    create or replace procedure GPU_DATA_EXTRACTOR_TEST(pid_billdate DATE) is
v_cnt      NUMBER;
c_limit   CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10000;

CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT DISTINCT intl_prod_id
      FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
           acct_bill ab
      WHERE abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
          AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
          AND abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id
          AND ab.bill_date = pid_billdate;

TYPE prod_ids_t IS TABLE OF apld_bill_rt.intl_prod_id%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
l_prod_ids   prod_ids_t;
begin

   execute immediate 'truncate table GPU_INV_TEST';

   v_cnt := 0;
  OPEN c1;

  LOOP
     FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO l_prod_ids LIMIT c_limit;
     
     EXIT WHEN l_prod_ids.COUNT = 0;

    FORALL indx IN 1 .. l_prod_ids.COUNT
    
      INSERT INTO GPU_INV_TEST
         SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
                AB.BILL_NO,
                AB.INV_ID,
                AB.BILL_DATE,
                ba2.bill_acct_id,
                ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
                AB.DUE_DATE,
                PG.CMPG_ID,
                ABR.NET_AMT,
                AB.DUE_AMT,
                P.PROD_NUM,
                pds.DST_ID,
                ABR.DESCR,
                p.intl_prod_id
           FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
                acct_bill ab,
                prod p,
                FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds,
                bill_acct_prod bap,
                bill_acct ba1,
                bill_acct ba2,
                prod_cmpg pg
          WHERE ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID
                AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id
                AND ba2.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id
                AND ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
                AND p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id(+)
                AND ABR.intl_prod_id = l_prod_ids(indx)
UNION
    SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
                AB.BILL_NO,
                AB.INV_ID,
                AB.BILL_DATE,
                ba1.bill_acct_id,
                ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
                AB.DUE_DATE,
                PG.CMPG_ID,
                ABR.NET_AMT,
                AB.DUE_AMT,
                P.PROD_NUM,
                pds.DST_ID,
                ABR.DESCR,
                p.intl_prod_id
           FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
                acct_bill ab,
                prod p,
                FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds,
                bill_acct_prod bap,
                bill_acct ba1,
                prod_cmpg pg
          WHERE ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID
                --AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id
                AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id
                AND ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
                AND p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id(+)
                AND ABR.intl_prod_id = l_prod_ids(indx);

      v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;

      IF MOD (v_cnt, 10000) = 0
      THEN
         COMMIT;
      END IF;
    COMMIT;  
    
    
    END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure treats everything, it just works in bulks of 10000 records, thus prone to parallelism.

There is a loop in the forall, the insert will be executed for all the records (10K)

Regarding the v_cnt mod, you can remove it (but not advised to) with no issues other than performances, the original author most likely found that the redo segments might get really big, so he's just commiting everywhile and so (but since he truncates the table in the beginning, this isn't an issue at all).

Comment: Hello, thank you for comment. I have almost 280.000 records which meets that conditions in the scripts above. So will it just takes 10.000 then stops or will it take everytime 10.000 and continues(like data chunks 10.000 and next 10.000 which goes on)? what do you think? I am newbie in the job that's why asking :)

Comment: As I said, it should be covering the whole lot, but works in 10K chunks, thus, this Might work in parallel if needed, this won't stop until the 280K are done.
You can always check the size of the resulting insert , you should find your records there.

Comment: the bulk collect here does not make any sense. the cursor is getting only one value that can be join with the selects below using a cte expression.

Comment: Bulk is used for to help parallelism, nothing else as far as I know, It indicates that each process can work on "bulk records" independently from the others.

Comment: @Gar where should I use EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;  c1 is cursor btw

Comment: The exit is already there :  EXIT WHEN l_prod_ids.COUNT = 0;
If you feel like this procedure never ends, please check the growth of the target table, this will be a good indicator on how the procedure is doing.

Comment: @Gar, the bulk collect is not helping anything in that procedure. it is a simple insert select. bulk collect does not help parallelism , is a better construction for loop using collections, but a cursor after all. Limit clause avoids memory issues, as bulk collect is a huge memory operation.

Comment: I greatly respect your opinion, though I cannot share it, bulk collection is added for parallelism, otherwise it is totally useless.

Comment: A bulk collect is a method of fetching data where the PL/SQL engine tells the SQL engine to collect many rows at once and place them in a collection. The SQL engine retrieves all the rows and loads them into the collection and switches back to the PL/SQL engine. All the rows are retrieved with only 2 context switches. There is no parallel work here, is a different and more efficient way to work with cursors. Nothing to do with Parallel DML or Parallel Processing using DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about `v_cnt mod`, as it's only used to commit every 10,000 loop iterations, and as each iteration loads 10,000 rows, in effect it is committing every  100,000,000 rows. As you only have 280K rows anyway it will never be used.

Comment: There's no parallel processing here and I don't see any opportunity for using it, unless maybe the driving cursor would benefit from it even though the loop and INSERT are necessarily serial, so I'm not sure what the comments about parallel processing are about.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any `bulk collect` in that procedure. It is non sense. Why ? Because you are not collecting values in the type and applying logic over them, you just get the `distinct intl_prod_id` in a cursor and make a select for each one, something you can easily solve with a CTE expression.

If you use also direct path, by applying the hint `append`, then you will get a much better procedure and huge boost in performance.

Keep in mind that for each row in the cursor, you need to run the insert/select, that implies to join all the tables involved in the operation for each value in the cursor. Try to apply the principle, the easier the better.

```
create or replace procedure GPU_DATA_EXTRACTOR_TEST(pid_billdate DATE) is

begin
    execute immediate 'truncate table GPU_INV_TEST';

   INSERT /*+append */ INTO GPU_INV_TEST
   with x as 
   (  SELECT /*+materialize */ DISTINCT intl_prod_id as intl_prod_id 
      FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
           acct_bill ab
      WHERE abr.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
          AND abr.TAX_CATG_ID = 'NOTAX'
          AND abr.acct_bill_id = ab.acct_bill_id
          AND ab.bill_date = pid_billdate 
    )
      SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
                AB.BILL_NO,
                AB.INV_ID,
                AB.BILL_DATE,
                ba2.bill_acct_id,
                ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
                AB.DUE_DATE,
                PG.CMPG_ID,
                ABR.NET_AMT,
                AB.DUE_AMT,
                P.PROD_NUM,
                pds.DST_ID,
                ABR.DESCR,
                p.intl_prod_id
           FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
                acct_bill ab,
                prod p,
                FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds,
                bill_acct_prod bap,
                bill_acct ba1,
                bill_acct ba2,
                prod_cmpg pg , 
                x
          WHERE ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID
                AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id
                AND ba2.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id
                AND ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
                AND p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id(+)
                AND ABR.intl_prod_id = x.intl_prod_id
    UNION
    SELECT AB.ACCT_BILL_ID,
                AB.BILL_NO,
                AB.INV_ID,
                AB.BILL_DATE,
                ba1.bill_acct_id,
                ba1.bill_acct_id parent_bill_acct_id,
                AB.DUE_DATE,
                PG.CMPG_ID,
                ABR.NET_AMT,
                AB.DUE_AMT,
                P.PROD_NUM,
                pds.DST_ID,
                ABR.DESCR,
                p.intl_prod_id
           FROM apld_bill_rt abr,
                acct_bill ab,
                prod p,
                FCBSADM.PROD_DST pds,
                bill_acct_prod bap,
                bill_acct ba1,
                prod_cmpg pg, 
                x
          WHERE ab.intl_bill_acct_id = ba1.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND AB.ACCT_BILL_ID = ABR.ACCT_BILL_ID
                --AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = ba2.parent_bill_acct_id
                AND ba1.intl_bill_acct_id = bap.intl_bill_acct_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = abr.intl_prod_id
                AND ABR.CHRG_TP = 'INSTALLMENT'
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = pds.intl_prod_id
                AND bap.intl_prod_id = p.intl_prod_id
                AND p.intl_prod_id = pg.intl_prod_id(+)
                AND ABR.intl_prod_id = x.intl_prod_id;

         COMMIT;
end;
```

Comment: This is the best solution if you do not want to use parallelism and want to do it sequentially, but generally, when working on over 100K records it would be more efficient to work in parallel , in which case the APPEND hint should be removed, and depending on the business rules it might be better to work in bulk (as the original developer did)

Comment: @Gar, you are not using paralllel work with bulk collect, because for every record in the cursor, you are making an insert based on joins. If you do that 100k times, you need to run the joins 100k times. A normal insert select in this case does that in one step, and 100k records is nothing for Oracle. Besides, this is not sequential, it is a overall process, as any insert select

Comment: also, whoever downvote this answer shows that he/she does not know anything about Oracle. If you are not applying any logic over the bulk collect values, and you can do it in a simple and easier way, then apply one of the fundamental development principles: the simpler the better

Comment: If you add APPEND the query won't go parallel, so if you have 48 cores, only 1 would be working whatever the default parallelism is.
If you run the query as it is, It might fire in parallel , but could (and I insist on the could) kill the redo logs.
If you run the OP query as it is, it might fire in parallel and won't hurt the Redo.
So all three ways are valid, depends on what you want : simpler code, cores use efficiency, Redos etc

Comment: if you add APPEND, the query will go in direct path, bypassing the buffer cache. Redo logs will not be killed as direct path operations are less redo consuming. The code truncates the table before starting, which means that the data there is transient. You could add the hint parallel and nologging as well, but the point here is that doing this you run a single select, using bulk collect you run the select with all the joins as many times as values in the cursor. By the way, 300M of normal defualt redo log files will not be killed by 100k rows. Ever

Comment: As I said, If you use the query "as it is" (I meant without the APPEND hint), it would kill the redos.  All I'm pointing to is that there will be always a trade off : simplicity of code / Speed / Efficiency etc

Comment: @Gar surely an INSERT SELECT is already "in bulk", so I'm not sure what "in bulk" advantage there could be with FORALL.